# Open (default) camera application *NOT* to upload a file

Tags: javascript, html, camera, progressive-web-apps

I need to open the camera application **NOT to upload a file** but basically open the camera application so the user can use the integrated QR scanner in said camera application.

When using an input with `accept="image/*"` like:

```
<input type="file" capture="environment" accept="image/*">
```

It would open the gallery on my Samsung phone and would open a (not thé) camera application on an Iphone but won't recognize QR codes like the actual camera application does. So neither does what I require.

It would be very close to the functionality behind the `href="mailto:` where it opens a mail application.

Is this possible with HTML or even Javascript?